# sscanf writing to a character array

Tags: c, scanf

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[40000]= "3 Hello World";
    int idvalue;
    char buf[4000];
    sscanf(buffer,"%d %s%s",&idvalue,buf);
    printf("%d->%s\n",idvalue,buf);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I have a variable buffer that is always of the type "integer rest of part". I want to copy the content of that variable into two new variables `idvalue` and `buf`. `idvalue` will contain that integer and `buf` will contain the rest of the part which can have spaces, integer, string, etc.
Write now `idvalue` is correctly copied but in the case of `buf` the value gets terminated after whitespace. Tell me a way to copy the whole rest of the part in a single string `buf`.

Comment: You have three format specifiers in your `sscanf` format string but only two pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the format specifier `%[^\n]` instead of `%s`.

This will tell `sscanf` to read and store any characters up until a newline (`\n`) into buff:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d%[^\n]", &idvalue, buf);
```

For other applications you could add to the characters inside of the `[]`, for example if you wanted to stop reading once you reached a newline *or* a tab: `[^\n\t]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a replacement sscanf line that should solve your problem.

```
 sscanf(buffer,"%d %[^\n]",&idvalue,buf);
```